# Octave time series Moving average

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, time-series, octave, financial

I have a matrix with each column represents a feature over time. I need to find the moving average of these values with a given window size.

Is there a function like the [one](http://www.mathworks.com/help/finance/tsmovavg.html) in MATLAB?

```
output = tsmovavg(vector, 's', lag, dim)
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the [FILTER](http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/filter.html) function. An example:

```
t = (0:.001:1)';                                %#'
vector = sin(2*pi*t) + 0.2*randn(size(t));      %# time series

wndw = 10;                                      %# sliding window size
output1 = filter(ones(wndw,1)/wndw, 1, vector); %# moving average
```

or even use the [IMFILTER](http://octave.sourceforge.net/image/function/imfilter.html) and [FSPECIAL](http://octave.sourceforge.net/image/function/fspecial.html) from the Image Package

```
output2 = imfilter(vector, fspecial('average', [wndw 1]));
```

One final option is using indexing (not recommended for very large vector)

```
%# get indices of each sliding window
idx = bsxfun(@plus, (1:wndw)', 0:length(vector)-wndw);
%'# compute average of each
output3 = mean(vector(idx),1);
```

Please note the difference in padding: `output1(wndw:end)` corresponds to `output3`

Comment: How to set moving average start samples?