# Nested for loop for moving window filter

Tags: matlab, octave

I want to implement nested for loop in MATLAB the first loop should run from 3 to n and inside this loop the second for loop should run for 1:5. My problem is I want to take averages of 5 numbers but a moving average. So i should start with average from elements 1 to 5 for first row, elements 2 to 6 for second row , elemets 3 to 7 for third row.

Please help me with this problem.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Octave time series Moving average](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114450/octave-time-series-moving-average)

Answer (score 0):

My *assumption* is, your are looking for something like this ... without a *nested for-loop*:

```
for i = 3:n
  some_average(i) = mean(some_data_matrix(i, i:(i+4)));
end
```

Though, your question needs further clarification.